# Disable features during silent installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have an installation that contains about 17 features. When running in UI mode user can
disable features. I am using standard Mondo UI.

I want to allow silent installation - meaning, user can provide /q parameter during installation. How features can be disabled in that mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ADDLOCAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367536%28VS.85%29.aspx) property to enable or disable the features. The features that are passed to this property only enabled and other features will be disabled. If you want to install all features pass "ALL" (ADDLOCAL =ALL) instead of listing all features.

```
msiexec /i "TestProject.msi" ADDLOCAL=Feature1,Feature3 /q
```