# Unselecting ALL features during silent installation

Tags: wix, wix3.5

[This is my original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535840/disable-features-during-silent-installation)

Now, what i need is to run installer as is all features are disabled. I want to get a result that only custom actions are executed. It works in UI. During silent installation, I canno't get the same result. I tried:

REMOVE=ALL parameter - but it doesn't seem to work.

Ideas on how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by providing names of all root features to REMOVE parameter and it did the job. While using REMOVE=ALL it's not working.